# Facebook Image Gallery on Website (PHP/JSON)

Tags: php, jquery, json, facebook-graph-api, image-gallery

I am trying to get a facebook gallery (https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.188384271935.125248.188249156935&type=3) in particular to display on a website.

All the JSON examples I have tried seem to be outdated with facebook's current API.

https://graphs.facebook.com/10151038651796936?fields=images pulls up the JSON data that I need. But when I plug it in to examples that I find, or even examples from Facebook's API it wont load. (using Jquery 1.9 hosted locally)

This is the code that I am trying to use, but I think it is outdated as per facebooks current API.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function (gallery_id) {
            var title = $('h2'),
                viewer = $('#viewer'),
                thumbs = $('#thumbs');

            // album info
            $.getJSON('//graph.facebook.com/' + gallery_id + '?callback=?', function(json, status, xhr) {
              title.html('<a href="' + json.link + '">' + json.name + '</a> from ' + json.from.name);
            });

            // images
            $.getJSON('//graph.facebook.com/' + gallery_id + '/photos?callback=?', function(json, status, xhr) {
              var imgs = json.data;

              viewer.attr('src', imgs[0].images[0].source)

              for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
                $('<img src="' + imgs[i].images[3].source + '" data-fullsize="' + imgs[i].images[0].source + '">').appendTo(thumbs);
              }

              $('img', thumbs).bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                viewer.attr('src', $(this).attr('data-fullsize'));
              });
            });
          })('188384271935'); //  put the gallery ID here
```

What I would like the code to do is be able to choose the amount of pictures displayed (most recent), and for the gallery ID to be able to be changed easily.

I am pretty unfamiliar with JSON, if you could show an example of a working snippet of code that does something along these lines I would GREATLY appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.  You should double-check that your jQuery library is indeed loading and that you have elements on the page that have `viewer` and `thumbs` IDs.  `viewer` should be an `img` tag and `thumbs` should be a block-level element of some sort, like a `div`.

Since you're not using `jQuery(document).ready` to call this, (at least not from the code provided) you should also make sure this script tag is included after the markup for `viewer` and `thumbs`.

As an aside, if you use `imgs[i].images[6].source` for your thumbnails, they'll be a little smaller.

Comment: wow... missing a ; on the view.attr line.... I'm a dummy... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any clue as to why this code doesnt work if you are signed into fb, or have certain fb cookies?

Comment: I assume you're pulling from galleries from public pages?  Are there any country or age restrictions for the pages themselves you might be hitting?  Beyond that I'm not sure I'd be much help as I'm not terribly familiar with Facebook's API myself.

Comment: as far as I know, the page is full public, and I only live 20 mins from the place so even if there was some kind of lock out like that, I dont think I would be.